# Plot RectangularChart3D in Mathematica 12

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I would like to have a 3d rectangle chart looks like the following:

[image]

Later on, I will use different transparent color for each small 3d rectangle. It seems that the function RectangleChart3D can give some results, but it only gives one row and not all of them.

does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: `RectangleChart3D` is one of those fake 3D plots, so you won't be able to easily get multiple rows. Depending on your data, you could use [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html) (only works for regular grids)

Comment: How about [`Histogram3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html)?

Comment: Would it not be simpler and easier to just (scale and) plot individual polygons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RectangleChart3D` with the option `ChartLayout -> "Grid"`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[10, {5, 5, 3}];

RectangleChart3D[data, 
   ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ViewPoint -> {10, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Add the option `ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.7]` to make the cuboids transparent:

[image]

To remove the polygon faces and the canvas:

```
RectangleChart3D[data, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Large, 
  ViewPoint -> {10, -5, 10}, 
  FaceGrids -> None, 
  "Canvas" -> False, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] /. {Directive[___], p_} :> { 
   p /. Polygon[a_,  VertexColors -> {c_, ___}] :>
    {Antialiasing -> True, EdgeForm[{Opacity[1], Thick, c}], FaceForm[], Polygon[a]}}
```

[image]